# Bot de música para discord

Tags: python, discord.py

Soy nuevo en el tema de la programación y tengo un bot de música para discord. Tengo el problema de que a mitad de una canción el bot deja de reproducir la misma. Es como si usara el comando `!stop` (el cual aún no he agregado al código). Quería saber si alguien podría ayudarme a resolver este inconveniente y ya si tiene algún tipo de sugerencia respecto al código es bienvenida.

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from pytube import YouTube


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Conectado como {bot.user.name}')`


@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
    await ctx.send(f'Conectado al canal de voz: {channel}')


@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client:
        await voice_client.disconnect()
        await ctx.send('Desconectado del canal de voz')
    else:
        await ctx.send('No estoy conectado a un canal de voz')


@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if not voice_client:
        await ctx.send('No estoy conectado a un canal de voz')
        return

try:
    video = YouTube(url)
    best_audio = video.streams.get_audio_only()
    url2 = best_audio.url

    audio_source = FFmpegPCMAudio(url2)
    voice_client.play(audio_source)

    await ctx.send('Reproduciendo música de YouTube')

    while voice_client.is_playing():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    await voice_client.disconnect()
    await ctx.send('Reproducción finalizada, desconectado del canal de voz')

except Exception as e:
    await ctx.send(f'Error al reproducir música: {str(e)}')



TOKEN = '*******'

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: necesitas poner el codigo. sin codigo no te podemos ayudar. No pongas links ni imagenes. Pon el codigo correctamente formateado como codigo

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Ya adite la pregunta en cuestion, Muchas gracias por decirme que era mejor directamente colocar el codigo

Answer (score 0):

El bot deja de reproducir la canción a mitad de la misma porque parece que se está produciendo una interrupción o una desconexión en el flujo del audio.

Una manera de solucionar el problema es configurando `FFmpeg` para que  se reconecte automáticamente cuando esto suceda.

Puedes hacerlo al inicializar `FFmpegPCMAudio` haciendo uso del parámetro `before_options`:

> before_options (Optional[str]) – Extra command line arguments to pass to ffmpeg before the -i flag.

```
audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(best_audio.url, before_options="-reconnect 1 -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 2")
```

---

Así quedaría tu comando:

```
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if not voice_client:
        await ctx.send('No estoy conectado a un canal de voz')
        return

    try:
        video = YouTube(url)
        best_audio = video.streams.get_audio_only()

        audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(
            best_audio.url,
            before_options="-reconnect 1 -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 2"
        )

        voice_client.play(audio_source)
        await ctx.send('Reproduciendo música de YouTube')

        while voice_client.is_playing():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

        await voice_client.disconnect()
        await ctx.send('Reproducción finalizada, desconectado del canal de voz')

    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f'Error al reproducir música: {str(e)}')
```

---

### Referencias:

- [discord.FFmpegPCMAudio](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#ffmpegpcmaudio)
- [Respuesta de SuperUser de donde obtuve los argumentos de FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/a/1050499)
- [Documentación FFmpeg relevante](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#http)